# How to stop tkinter looping indefinitely?

Tags: python, tkinter, while-loop

I'm trying to add a tkinter GUI to a simple text-based game made in python but I'm struggling with the game loop, which either runs infinitely or not at all. I would like the game to ask the player what they want to do, then do something based on that, then return to asking the player what they want. The problem I'm having is instead of calling the function once, it calls it repeatedly.

```
while playing is True:
    getAreaDesc()       
    requestPlayerMove()
    if action == 1:
        explore()
    elif action == 2:
        travel()
    elif action == 3:
        rest()
    window.update_idletasks()
    window.update()
```

I'm fairly sure I know what is causing the problem. As I understand it, this is because the value for action is determined by a tkinter button (with a command setting the value for action) so as soon as a button is pressed, it calls the relevant function. Then it checks again but as the action is still the same, it calls the function again. And so on and it doesn't stop until a different button is pressed and a different. I think it's like a lightswitch in the sense that once it's on it stays on, even though the switch is only flicked once.

However, even if I am right about why it calls the functions continuously, I can't think of a way to prevent that occuring which doesn't simply stop the loop.
I've tried resetting action as part of the functions, but that causes it to do nothing beyond ask for player choice. Similarly, trying to nest the if/elif parts comes to the same result, and using after() changes nothing but the speed at which it loops relentlessly. And those were my good ideas. I tried putting input() back in to wait for the player and that went about as well as you could imagine.

I'm sure it's something daft I'm missing, hopefully not offensively stupid, but I'm at a loss and any help would be very appreciated. Thanks for your time reading this, if your patience lasted this far.

Comment: You shouldn't use `while` loops when using `tkinter`. You bindings and callbacks instead. If that isn't enough you can also use `.after` scripts. `tkinter`'s mainloop was designed to do everything that you will need. When the user clicks on a button, execute that instruction. There is no need for `if action == 1`, `elif action == 2`, ...

Comment: I used the action = 1 etc, so I could use the same buttons for multiple things. I guess I wasn't being efficient, I was actually being lazy. So I'll change that to have one button per action and then just swap out the buttons as needed. That's probably why it didn't work with mainloop as well, because I was trying to make a bastardised loop instead of using the buttons properly. I'll try that tomorrow and update the question if it works. Even if it doesn't, thanks for your help

Comment: I don't know if you already know this but you can change the button's text/command using `<tkinter.Button>.config(text=<new text>, command=<new command>)`. Tell me if you need more help

Comment: I didn't actually know that, but that looks the perfect solution. Thanks a lot for your help, Lizzard

Comment: [Here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_gui_programming.htm) is a source I like using when dealing with `tkinter` I like it and it includes some examples so it is pretty understandable (it doesn't include all of the possible methods of some widgets but the most common are there) also I suggest taking a look at some `tkinter` tutorials on YouTube like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YXPyB4XeYLA)

Comment: Providing just a while loop code cannot let others to understand your issue.  Better provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).